# C# - How to create Http Request from raw string

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a lot of strings from Fiddler (or Postman) with raw requests - they are just a plain text strings, e.g.

```
GET http://www.google.com/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
```

How to create http request from such string just passing it as it is to somewhere? Something like this

```
var requestStr = @"GET http://www.google.com/ HTTP/1.1"
                         + @"\r\nHost: www.google.com"
                         + "\r\n";
client.Send(requestStr);
```

I know about TcpClient, but maybe something more simple is there.

Comment: You can Check HttpClient. For more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Comment: With HttpClient you have to specify headers, body manually, it has nothing where you can pass raw request string.

Comment: What you described as "plain text strings" are not plan in fact. They are well formatted strings to show the bits of HTTP requests (verb, URL, protocol version, headers). By default, it would be your responsibility to parse the strings and generate corresponding requests via `HttpWebRequest` or `HttpClient`.